# How to position the Simple text to the same height as text in textbox in IE7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I want to Align the text **'Start new Search'** at same height as the text in the input box. This issue happens only in **IE7**. Below is the corresponding image,html and CSS to it

```
<span class="search_new_search_box"> Start new search&nbsp;&nbsp;

  <input id="search_box_second" class="search_results_input" type="text" value="$searchTO.getSearchTerm()" onfocus="if (this.value=='Please enter a keyword') {this.value = '';}"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>

  <span style="float:left"><input type="image" src="images/bttn_search_result.png" value="submit"  /></span>
```

and here is the CSS to it

```
.search_new_search_box{
    font:normal 12px/24px AntennaRegular, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    float:left;
    padding-top:3px;
}
.search_results_input {
    width:300px;
    height:30px;
    font:normal 12px/24px AntennaRegular, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    background-color:#eee;
    border:solid 1px #ccc;
    line-height:30px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the vertical-align on those elements to something. This clears it up for me in IE7.  For instance, here's an example with it set to `vertical-align:middle` ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tKU2L/1/)).

```
.search_new_search_box{
    font:normal 12px/24px AntennaRegular, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    float:left;
    padding-top:3px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.search_results_input {
    width:300px;
    height:30px;
    font:normal 12px/24px AntennaRegular, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    background-color:#eee;
    border:solid 1px #ccc;
    line-height:30px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

You don't have to specify middle, just do something that makes sense for both of them.  Also, not all of the vertical-align values will work right (baseline, et. al.)  Also, you'll want to make this IE7 only as it doesn't look right with other browsers.